# Why is UpdatePanel Trigger not recognizing my ControlID

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, triggers, updatepanel

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" 
            ClientIDMode="Static"
            AllowPaging="true" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" 
            OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/eg.png" CommandName="er" ID="ero" runat="server" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/de.png" runat="server"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Panel ID="pop" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C#:

```
protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "er")
    {
        pop.CssClass += " set100";

        up.Update();
    }
}
```

The above isn't working for me. So I added the following inside my UpdatePanel:

```
//...
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ero" />
    </Triggers>
//...
```

Now I am getting the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

A control with ID 'ero' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'up'.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

How an I resolve the issue?

Comment: Which part isn't working exactly? The class or the update or something else?

Comment: Well when I click on the ImageButton nothing happens. It seems nothing fires from inside the UpdatePanel.

Comment: Was playing around with it but it's very hard to recreate, and test without data. You're sure the class `set100` is not being applied? Maybe it's already there, or maybe the CSS doesn't show up properly? Does a breakpoint take you to `gv_RowCommand`? Just checking.

Comment: Thanks for checking up on it. Yes i do have a breakpoint and it doesn't hit. The project compiles without any error but nothing happens when I click the button. So ODD! It never happened before and I am really confused as to why it's not working now.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [**solution**](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1028271/PostBack-Whole-Page-Using-GridView-Itemtemplate-Co):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

    }

    foreach (var item in gv.Rows)
    {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) ((GridViewRow)item).FindControl("ero");
        // Get current ScriptManager on the page
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(btn);
    }
            
}
```